# The mobile burger button only works sometimes

Tags: wordpress, hamburger-menu

I am having some issues with my wordpress modis theme hamburger button. It's the most random thing I have ever seen with creating websites. Some times when you click the button the shows the pages and on other times it simply does nothing when you click it. I don't know if it's a bad idea to send the link of the website but I will do it any ways [www.dcbeauty.co.za](http://www.dcbeauty.co.za) would much appreciate if someone could help. Thank you

Comment: why don't you include at least some of the code/css/html for the button so this can be a relevant question. Links are generally discouraged

Comment: general tips: check the javascript console for errors. If no errors, inspect DOM to see if another element covers it, or sprinkle some `console.log` calls into the functions

Comment: I am not even sure where to look for that I am assuming it's in the themes directory.

Comment: in your browser, hit F12, choose "Console" tab and look for error when the button fails. You can also right-click on the hamburger menu and choose "Inspect..." and see what you are really clicking on (latest versions seem to require you to do it twice...)

Comment: There is no errors in the console. It's weird it works perfectly on pc when I make the Browser smaller but when it's on mobile it's bit faulty. I really don't know what to do

Comment: since you didn't create it and don't have access to source code, not really a programming questions

Comment: There is source code with in the link the problem I don't know where to look. If I knew I would fix it my self but I don't. I don't know if it's css or js it has to be the problem.

Comment: I have noticed really weird thing it works fine one my huawei 20 mate. But not on my samsung s20 fe 4g and also my older samsung phone it's not working

Comment: well, in designesia.js, there is the javascript to handle the click `           jQuery('#menu-btn').on("click", ...`  it changes some classes and styles.